# Find missing id between an array of objects and an array of id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
const users = [

{
 name:John,
 id:1
},
{
 name:Dude,
 id:2
}
]
```

And an array of ids:

```
const ID = [1,2,5]
```

I would like to to know that 5 is the missing ID so I can fetch that ID.

I have tried nesting for loops

```
  users.forEach((user, index) => {
    let userExists = false;
    ID.forEach((id) => {
      if (user.id == id) {
        userExists = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    if (!userExists) {
      console.log('user doesnt exists');
    }
  });
```

There might be a simple solution but currently I can't wrap my head around it

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very easy to do that, use `filter()`

```js
const users = [
{
 name:"John",
 id:1
},
{
 name:"Dude",
 id:2
}
]

const ID = [1,2,5]

console.log(ID.filter(x=> !users.find(f=> f.id == x)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `ID` in place, using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through each user and [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove an item from `ID`.

```js
const users = [ { name: 'John', id: 1 }, { name: 'Dude', id: 2 }, ];
const ID = [1, 2, 5];

users.forEach(({ id }) => ID.splice(ID.indexOf(id), 1));

console.log(ID);
```